# How to start the app at boot time without displaying device company name?

Tags: android, splash-screen

My android app should be run on an akai android device having display in a T.V. I am running my app as a launcher perfectly, when I am on the t.v it is displaying the t.v company name, akai company name then only my app is running.

I want my app should run immediately when the device is on without displaying t.v company or akai smartbox company or what ever.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that you cannot make change to a device's boot animations without rooting it, although you can run your app on device boot, by adding the onbootcompleted permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

The graphics you are talking about are most probably displayed by the *bootloader* and *android kernel*, so they happen much before your application even has the opportunity to run.

You should create your own firmware for the device in order to change them.